# returning a `number` from `Observable<Array<number>>`

Tags: angular, rxjs

I found this piece of code in a tutorial on RxJS. I am new to RxJs. I have some doubts.

The code seems to return `number` while the observable seem to be of type `Observable<Array<number>>` (I suppose it means that the Observable is expected to return an `Array<number>`.

**Question1: Is it possible to return a `number` from `Array<number>`?**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
      <b>Angular 2 Component Using Observables!</b>


  <h6 style="margin-bottom: 0">VALUES:</h6>
  <div *ngFor="let value of values">- {{ value }}</div>

  <h6 style="margin-bottom: 0">ERRORs:</h6>
  <div>Errors: {{anyErrors}}</div>

  <h6 style="margin-bottom: 0">FINISHED:</h6>
  <div>Finished: {{ finished }}</div>

  <button style="margin-top: 2rem;" (click)="init()">Init</button>
`
})
export class MyApp {




 private data: Observable<Array<number>>;
  private values: Array<number> = [];
  private anyErrors: boolean;
  private finished: boolean;

  constructor() {
  }

  init() {
      this.data = new Observable(observer => {


     setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next(42);
      }, 1000);

      setTimeout(() => {
          observer.next(43);
      }, 2000);

      setTimeout(() => {
          observer.complete();
      }, 3000);
  });

  let subscription = this.data.subscribe(
      value => this.values.push(value),
      error => this.anyErrors = true,
      () => this.finished = true
  );
  }

}
```

**Question 2:** When does the observable start execution? I suppose the code passed to an observable is executed asynchronously. In above piece of code, is it possible that by the time the observable is subscribed to, some piece of code has already been executed (and thus some subscribers might miss the data)?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Code formated Lazar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question1: Is it possible to return a number from Array?

Yes, because TypeScript checks only exist a compile-time, and can only be applied if you specify types correctly. Your code should be

```
this.data = new Observable<Array<number>>(observer => {
  ...
```

In that case, TypeScript *will* generate compilation errors because you try to emit numbers instead of emitting arrays of numbers. But remember that, at runtime, all these types don't exist anymore, and you only have `Observable`, which can emit anything.

> Question 2: When does the observable start execution?

In this case, when you subscribe to it.